# Why does my libgdx app just display the badlogic.jpg instead of my start screen?

Tags: libgdx

I have been looking at example libgdx games.  It looks like https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc is the closest thing to a game I would like to make.  I am able to download, compile and execute the Cuboc game no problem.  So I follow the instructions for creating a libgdx project (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) and I am able to compile and execute the resulting project which just displays the badlogic.jpg file.

[image]

So I start aping the code from Cuboc into my game, which I am calling Malfunction. All I want to do is display my "MainMenu" screen which simply display a png file which I copied from the Cuboc game.

Here's what I have in my Malfunction project:

```
// Malfunction.java
package com.redcricket.malfunction;

import com.redcricket.malfunction.screens.MainMenu;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class Malfunction extends Game {
    private String TAG = "MAL";

    @Override
    public void create () {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "MainMenu (Game)");
        setScreen(new MainMenu(this));
    }
}
```

... and this java file ...

```
// MainMenu.java
package com.redcricket.malfunction.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class MainMenu extends MalfunctionScreen {
    TextureRegion title;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    float time = 0;
    private String TAG = "MAL";

    public MainMenu(Game game) {
        super(game);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "MainMenu (Game)");

    }

    @Override
    public void show () {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "show()");

        title = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/title.png")), 0, 0, 480, 320);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 480, 320);
    }

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "render (float)");

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(title, 0, 0);
        batch.end();

        time += delta;
        if (time > 1) {
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ANY_KEY) || Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
//              game.setScreen(new IntroScreen(game));
                Gdx.app.log(TAG, "all done ...");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

... and this java file ...

```
// MalfunctionScreen
package com.redcricket.malfunction.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public abstract class MalfunctionScreen implements Screen {
    Game game;

    public MalfunctionScreen (Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void show () {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide () {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume () {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }
}
```

Update: I also have this java code ...

```
package com.redcricket.malfunction.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.redcricket.malfunction.Malfunction;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new Malfunction(), config);
    }
}
```

So why does this screen appear when I run my modified version of Malfunction?

[image]

Also none of my calls to `Gdx.app.log` ever show up in logcat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oops! *redfaced* I made a typo in the name of the file I trying to open.  In my assets/data folder the file was named `tile.png` not `title.png`.  Thanks to Justin-C on #libgdx irc